# Character.valueOf

Tags: java

I run this method:

```
String str=Character.valueOf(char).toString()
```

The output comes like a small square at console and just like a bar code in the file. What the actual format of the output is, also the output is not able to copy.

Comment: There are several problems here.  I assume you are trying to create a string from a char?

Comment: If you're on Windows and try to print a non latin character, you'll have settings to make to see it (and good luck if it's a corean char). What's the value of char ?

Comment: @Abhinav It all has to do with the tool that you use to see your character. Your character is a Unicode character, and your console or you file viewer may not support all unicode characters and it simply represents them with a empty square. What is the character that you are using and what tool are you using to view your file?

Comment: As Joachim said, you haven't provided enough information for us to help you in a productive way. If you're used to traditional forums, you'll probably come back in a few hours and be surprised by how fast people have responded here, but you can edit your question to clarify it at any time. I'll happily vote you up and cast a reopen vote if you do.

Comment: @Abhinav: well, you're trying to display [U+0000](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0000/index.htm). That's not going to be a useful character to display. The lower numbers are generally control characters with no visual representation (by default).

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Then how can i view these null characters

Comment: @Abhinav: what do you want to see? What is your goal? The NULL character has **no visual representatzion**, so what is it, that you expect to see? If you just want to display *something*, then print the numeric value of the character code, but that was already your input.

Comment: @Joachim: Actually, i have to enter some null characters inside the Websphere MQ, and i'm using Netbeans 6.8 for development the applications. Problem is that, when i print null character in file, it shows like square but when i put this null chracter inside the MQ, it convert the whole string or character in HexaAscii internally, and the value became changed. Websphere Mq takes null character as a different way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

`Character.valueOf(char)` simply takes a `char` and returns a `Character` wrapper instance representing the same value. Using `toString()` on that returns a `String` containing only that single charcter.

So if your initial `char` value represents a printable character, then the result should be just as printable.

If, however, you use an arbitrary numeric value (especially, if you use 0, 1 or very high values) as your starting point, then the result will be a String containing a single Unicode character with that codepoint. That's unlikely to be a useful result.

In other words: *crap in, crap out*.

What is your actual input value and what do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String.valueOf(c);
```

.toString() offers a string representation of an object and that can be anything. What you want is not the string representation of the Character object. You want to convert/create a  string from a char.

Comment: But isn't your code doing exactly the same thing as OP's, albeit the right way? What I mean is, there's no value of `ch` in `System.out.println(String.valueOf(ch).equals(Character.valueOf(ch).toString()));` that will produce the output `false`.

Comment: There is the code: int ii = Integer.parseInt("00", 16); char cc = (char) ii; String str= Character.valueOf(c).toString() and i'm using Netbeans 6.8 in windows environment